# My View Is not created when I create custom Layout

Tags: android, webview

My View Is not created when I call MyWebView from MainActivity. It gives error in logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.com/com.abc.com.MainActivity}:

 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.abc.com.MyWebView
```

Main Activity-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new MyWebView (this,getApplicationContext()); 
}

}


public class MyWebView extends WebView{




public MyWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


WebView mwebview;

Activity act;
String webView_url;
RelativeLayout layout;


public MyWebView(Activity _acActivity, Context _cont) {
    super(_cont);
    act = _acActivity;
    _context = _cont;

      ViewGroup wkll = new ViewGroup(_context) {

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };      
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tlp =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        mwebview = new MyWebView(_context);
        wkll.addView(mwebview);
        mwebview.setLayoutParams(tlp);
    mwebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}
}
```

Comment: You may have an error in your activity_main.xml. Can you post it?

Comment: you do realise that even after fixing your XML layout (might be just a case of cleaning and recompile) your MyWebView won't be there because you're not adding it to the layout, right?